# ADT update Actionbar Setup

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-actionbar

So I have Updated ADT to the latest Version.
So Google has decided to Add `appcompact_v7` default.

But when I create an Custom menu layout file for custom Actionbar Setup. I got bunch of errors. My xml for custom actionbar Layout.

```
custom_menu.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And My MainActivity.java file for inflating this Actionbar is.

```
package com.example.actionbar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

And Error is that R.java file deletes. So basically there is an problem in XML file. But why? I used to do this in previous adt version where I manually needed to add v7_appcompact library.

Comment: Eventually, you will run into problems in that `appcompat` does not use `android:showAsAction`. Instead, you need to declare a custom namespace (e.g., `app`) and use `app:showAsAction`. In terms of `R.java` not being generated, look for resources or the manifest with errors. There should be something specific. You can also check the Errors view in Eclipse. It's possible that your error is the problem I mentioned above, if Lint is now checking for this.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeh you were right. I added another line  `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and problem solved.

Comment: @CommonsWare But the thing is that emulator is not showing search Icon. on the top of the actionbar